# Mimic Tomcat's JNDI datasource for Crystal Reports Java API in stand-alone program

Tags: java, tomcat, crystal-reports, jndi, crystal-reports-export

Apparently this Tomcat data source gets registered in JNDI.  The crystal reports API will then find the "jdbc/TESTDB" (below) under the JNDI name of "TESTDB".  What is the easiest way to set this up in a stand-alone program?  I have several data-sources reports, so my preferred method is to configure all JNDI entries so any that are needed will be referenced and used on-demand.  Existing reports will not change and reference the ODBC connections.

I need to mimic this JNDI Tomcat entry in a stand-alone application.  I'm not concerned about any of the max parameters:

```
<Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/TESTDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="user" password="passwd" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbserver:1521:db1"/>
</Context>
```

This is the crystal reports example that shows this setup in action using Tomcat:

http://www.javathinking.com/2011/09/using-the-crystal-reports-java-api-to-generate-pdf/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to start a standalone JNDI server (and register some resources)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861874/easy-way-to-start-a-standalone-jndi-server-and-register-some-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a JNDI provider.  SimpleJNDI - http://code.google.com/p/osjava/wiki/SimpleJNDI - is usable in a application scenario outside a Java EE container.

You will need to investigate how to represent the data structure that Crystal Report needs, in the formats supported by SimpleJNDI.

Comment: It was a bit tricky setting up SimpleJNDI, they provide an example but not documentation.  Because you knew it would work, I took the effort and it payed off.  Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using the 'ini' configuration method.  I left the jndi.properties file unchanged.  I created 1 .ini file for each potential ODBC data connection used in the reports.  The name of the ini file xyz.ini matches the name of my datasource in the report (without the .ini) .. so xyz is in the report.  Each data source name appears only once in the configuration.  I removed extra config files (any not mentioned here).

I have opened a bug report about a missing class: http://code.google.com/p/osjava/issues/detail?id=13

Comment: This SimpleJNDI project is not under active development anymore. There is a GitHub clone with bug fixes and some new features maintained by me. See https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI .