# Create InitialContext from context.xml in plain java application

Tags: java, jndi, initial-context

As the question implies, I have a simple java app (aka a "simple main") that needs to initialize a hibernate connection whose information is in `context.xml`.

After lots of searching and with some hacks [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861874/easy-way-to-start-a-standalone-jndi-server-and-register-some-resources) I concluded to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JNDI provider is needed and RMI registry has one...
    try {
        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        System.out.println("RMI registry ready.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception starting RMI registry:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new InitialContext().readContextXml("context.xml");//of course there is nothing like that. But is there an equivalent?
    String result = thatWillConnectWithHibernate();
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static String thatWillConnectWithHibernate() {
    //does stuff
}
```

So is there a *simple* way to create an InitialContext from an xml file? I'm not interested in parsing the file manually, I can do that my self.